# ¿Es posible cambiar el puerto de ejecución de Live Server en VSCode?

Tags: vscode

Al iniciar Live Server en VSCode, este se ejecuta en el puerto 5500. Lo que quiero saber es si es posible cambiar ese puerto para que la extensión se ejecute en otro puerto, y de ser posible ¿cómo podría hacerse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es posible cambiar el puerto, debes presionar la tecla **f1** en Visual Studio Code y seleccionar **Open Settings(JSON)**, luego ubicar donde están los parámetros de liveserver y agregar la siguiente línea

```
"liveServer.settings.port": 4455,
```

Donde 4455 puedes reemplazarlo por el puerto que desees para liveserver.

Ese y otros parámetros puedes encontrarlos en la documentación en el siguiente link:
https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/blob/HEAD/docs/settings.md